# how to copy a column from another file when the ID's matches

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have 2 files,

```
head file1

    1   115258827   12 HG00099
    1   115258827   5 HG00100
    1   115258827   8 HG00101
    1   115258827   6 HG00103
    1   115258827   4 HG00108
    1   115258827   3 HG00110
    1   115258827   4 HG00111
    1   115258827   2 HG00114
    1   115258827   8 HG00115
    1   115258827   5 HG00116
```

and another file

```
head file2
HG00096 0|0
HG00097 0|0
HG00099 0|0
HG00100 0|1
HG00101 0|0
HG00102 0|0
HG00103 0|0
HG00105 0|0
HG00106 0|0
HG00107 0|0
```

I want to check if the last column of file1 matches the first column of file2, add the second column of file 2 to file1, ending up with something like

```
head desired
1   115258827   12 HG00099 0|0
1   115258827   5 HG00100  0|1
1   115258827   8 HG00101  0|0
1   115258827   6 HG00103  0|0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{seen[$1]=$2; next} seen[$NF]{print $0, seen[$NF]}' file2 file1
```

With the key of column$1 save the corresponding value of column$2 into an associated array called *seen* when *awk* reads only from *file2* where `NR==FNR` (always true for first input file when there are multiple input files to read), `NR` will set to 1 on first record/line read by *awk* and incrementing until all records/lines read either if single input file or multiple files; `FNR` will set to 1 on first record/line read by *awk* and incrementing until all records/lines read in current input file and will reset back to 1 for the next file.

The next block if the value of last column matched with the same key value in array seen, then print the entire line from *file1* and value of same key in array.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the field that you want to merge/join the data on is sorted:

```
$ join -1 4 -o1.1,1.2,1.3,0,2.2 file1 file2
1 115258827 12 HG00099 0|0
1 115258827 5 HG00100 0|1
1 115258827 8 HG00101 0|0
1 115258827 6 HG00103 0|0
```

This joins the two files on the fourth column of `file1` (specified using `-1 4`, since it's not the first column in that file) and the first column of `file2` (these are the columns that the files needs to be sorted on).

The `-o` flag tells `join` what fields we'd like to see in the output, and from what file they are to be taken (`1.3` means "the third field from the first file", for example, and `0` means the join field).

The benefit of using `join` is that neither file has to be read into memory completely.

---

If the files are not sorted, you may either pre-sort them once and for all using

```
sort -k4 -o file1 file1
sort     -o file2 file2
```

or, if you're using a shell that understands process substitution, you may sort them at the same time as you do the join using

```
join -1 4 -o1.1,1.2,1.3,0,2.2 <( sort -k4 file1 ) <( sort file2 )
```

It's the sorted data that allows `join` to only keep a few lines of each file in memory at a time.